# Drawing ticket winners in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to draw winners of a lottery game, I'm just quite unsure of how to decide WHICH user should win according to the ticket number.

Users who buy tickets are put behind the users who bought tickets before them.

```
var lotteryTickets = [
    {
    name: 'John Smith',
    tickets: 291
  },
  {
    name: 'Bob the Builder',
    tickets: 302
  },
  {
    name: 'Elizabeth',
    tickets: 72
  }
]

var lotteryTotal = 0;
lotteryTickets.forEach(function(data){
    lotteryTotal = lotteryTotal + data.tickets;
})

$('.tickets').text(lotteryTotal);

var winningTicket = parseInt(Math.random() * lotteryTotal);
$('.winner').text(winningTicket);
```

How could I decide properly which player would win the lottery?
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwk3np7r/5/)

Comment: It would have you greatly if you were keeping track of which tickets everyone had, and not just how many.

Comment: @egc8 it shouldn't matter. John Smith automatically has 0 - 291, Bob has 291 - (291+302) etc.

Comment: OK so what happens if Bob comes back later and buys 100 more tickets?

Comment: @ecg8 he gets another entry after Elizabeth with 100 more tickets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looping through the users:

```js
var ticket = 0;
var winner = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < lotteryTickets.length; i++) {
    ticket += lotteryTickets[i].tickets;
  if (winningTicket < ticket) {
    winner = i;
    break;
  }
}

$('.user').text(lotteryTickets[winner].name);
```

You could possibly merge this with the first loop you had to count the total number of tickets.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/531ujhck/1/)

Comment: Fixed. Sorry, I put a `>` instead of `<`

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

A brute force way would be to travers the lotteryTickets array again.

```
function getWinner(lotteryTickets,winningTicket){
var count = 0
lotteryTickets.forEach(function(data){
    count += data.tickets
    if(count >= winningTicket){ 
         return data.name
    }
   }
```

Comment: Returns `undefined`